# Вопрос по порядку вызова конструктора базового класса

Tags: java, конструктор

```
class B {
    private B() {
        System.out.println("No args constructor B");
    }
    protected B(String str) {
        System.out.println("Constructor with string B");
    }
}

class A extends B {
    public A() {
        this("some string");
        System.out.println("No args constructor A");
    }
    public A(String str) {
        super(str);
        System.out.println("Constructor with string A");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new A();
    }
}
```

На просторах интернета не нашел точного ответа на вопрос. Прошу подсказать, верно ли я понимаю порядок вызова конструктора базового класса:
Если в конструкторе потомке (Конструктор1) первой строкой вызвать другой конструктор потомка (Конструктор2), то вызов конструктора базового класса из Конструктора1 произведен не будет, вместо этого управление будет передано сразу в конструктор 2 и уже там, если нет вызова другого конструктора потомка, будет вызван конструктор базового класса.
Я правильно понимаю логику инициализации?

Answer (score 0):

при инициализации объекта, компилятор вызовет сначала дефолтный конструктор(который без аргументов), **он неявно создаётся во всех классах**, если его не переопределить.

если у класса есть "родитель", то по средствам ключевого слова `super()` будет вызываться конструктор "родителя" потом его "родителя" и тд до самого верха, пока не вызовется конструктор класса `Object` от которого в java наследуются все классы.

если написать следующее

```
public class Main extends Object{
}
```

ide напишет `Class 'Main' explicitly extends 'java.lang.Object'`
типо зачем ты мне это пишешь, я и так знаю что всё наследуется от Object

если написать так

```
class Class1{
    public Class1() {
        System.out.println("class1");
    }
}
class Class2 extends Class1{
    public Class2() {
        System.out.println("class2");
    }
}
class Class3 extends Class2{
    public Class3() {
        System.out.println("class3");
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Class3 class3 = new Class3();
    }
}
```

то вывод будет следующий

```
class1
class2
class3
```

получается своего рода лесенка, перед тем как создать обьект, сначала вызовется конструктор родительского класса, потом его родителя и тд, пока не дойдёт до главного папы(`Object`), а далее будут вызывается конструкторы по "лесенке" вниз.

Comment: _компилятор вызовет сначала дефолтный конструктор(который без аргументов)_ - Это неверно, вызов дефолтного конструктора при наличии пергруженного конструктора НЕ гарантирован

Comment: @Nowhere Man я могу ошибаться, не спорю...но , вызов конструктора не гарантирован!!?? а как обьект тогда создаётся, просветите меня пожалуйста

Comment: Я имел в виду, что не всякий конструктор дефолтный; при перегрузке конструкторов (создании конструкторов с параметрами) "дефолтный" конструктор придётся создавать явным порядком.

Answer (score 0):

Если бы вы запустили код в своём вопросе, вы бы увидели следующий вывод:

```
Constructor with string B
Constructor with string A
No args constructor A
```

То есть ваше понимание логики инициализации вполне корректно:

- При вызове конструктора без параметров `new A()` происходит вызов **перегруженного** конструктора `A(String str)`
- При вызове перегруженного конструктора `A(String str)` происходит вызов аналогичного конструктора *базового класса* `protected B(String str)`.  Вызов **дефолтного** конструктора базового класса в данном случае невозможен (например, при помощи `super();`), так как он определён как приватный!
- Завершается перегруженный конструктор базового класса, код возвращается в перегруженный конструктор потомка.
- Завершается перегруженный конструктор потомка, код возвращается в конструктор без параметров потомка.